# Survey - calculate scores based on answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, survey

I am trying to create a survey which calculates the percentages of scores once the user clicks submit.  The category answers should, "verbal communication", "non-verbal communication" and written communication.  When the assessment is finished a score should be displayed.  Scoring should be shown as percentages shown in a graph or scale. In addition answers or scores must be retained.  If someone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Survey</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <main class="content" role="main">
    <div class="grid-100">
      <div class="contained">
        <div class="grid-100">
          <h3>KeyPath Survey</h3>
          </br>
          <form action="">
            <fieldset>
              <div>
                <label for="">1. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">2. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">3. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">4. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">5. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">6. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">7. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">8. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">9. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="">10. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                <div class="form-item">
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-footer">
        <button class="button primary">Submit Survey</button>
      </div>

    </div></main>

</body>



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Survey</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <main class="content" role="main">
        <div class="grid-100">
          <div class="contained">
            <div class="grid-100">
              <h3>KeyPath Survey</h3>
              </br>
              <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">1. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">2. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">3. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">4. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">5. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">6. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">7. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">8. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">9. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label for="">10. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
                    <div class="form-item">
                      <select name="" id="">
                        <option value="Employed">Select One</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Verbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                        <option value="Employed">Written Communication</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-footer">
            <button class="button primary">Submit Survey</button>
          </div>

        </div></main>

    </body>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </html>




  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c7pcwLxf/ - Here is a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery and chart.js, you can read in the answers and chart them when you submit the form, then store the values to localStorage so that your score is retained.

Since localStorage doesn't work in the SO sandbox, here's a pen https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/eEMGYN

```js
var $selects = $("select"),
  data,
  ctx = $("#myChart"),
  config = {
    selected: 0,
    type: "pie",
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      pieceLabel: {
        render: function(args) {
          var selected = function() {
            var out = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              out = out + data[i];
            }
            return out;
          };
          var percentage = Math.round(args.value / selected() * 100) + "%";
          $('#'+args.label).text(percentage);
          return percentage;
        },
        fontSize: 14,
        fontStyle: "bold",
        fontColor: "#fff",
        fontFamily: '"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace'
      }
    },

    data: {
      labels: ["verbal", "non-verbal", "written"],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [0, 0, 0],
          backgroundColor: ["#09c", "#c00011", "green"]
        }
      ]
    }
  };

myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

$(".submit").on("click", function(e) {
  var results = { v: 0, n: 0, w: 0 },
    hasSelected = 0;
  e.preventDefault();
  $selects.each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
      results[val]++;
      hasSelected = 1;
    }
  });
  if (hasSelected) {
    data = [];
    $.each(results, function(k, v) {
      data.push(v);
    });
  } else {
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  }
  config.data.datasets[0].data = data;
  myChart.update();
  localStorage.data = JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
.grid-100, .graph {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/emn178/Chart.PieceLabel.js/master/build/Chart.PieceLabel.min.js"></script>
<main class="content" role="main">
  <div class="grid-100">
    <form action="">
      <div class="contained">
        <div class="grid-100">
          <h3>KeyPath Survey</h3>
          </br>
          <fieldset>
            <div>
              <label for="">1. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">2. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">3. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">4. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">5. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">6. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">7. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">8. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">9. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="">10. Which of the following describes you best?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-75 grid-parent">
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="v">Verbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="n">Nonverbal Communication</option>
                    <option value="w">Written Communication</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-footer">
        <button class="button primary submit">Submit Survey</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
  <div class="graph">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</main>
<div>
  Score: Verbal <span id="verbal">0</span>
  Non-Verbal <span id="non-verbal">0</span>
  Written <span id="written">0</span>
</div>
```